# How to store files under Cordova permanently

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-file

I have been using the plugova-plugin-file plugin for storing downloaded files, the problem I have is on the IOS platform, but after a while, these files are automatically deleted from the folder , I tried all the directories offered by this plugin:

```
cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory
cordova.file.applicationDirectory
cordova.file.documentsDirectory
cordova.file.dataDirectory
cordova.file.cacheDirectory
cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory
cordova.file.tempDirectory
```

But it always bug,

Thank you for your help

Comment: There're few steps you need to follow to save downloaded files on device. Check your device permissions and follow this link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Comment: I have track of document, but I have the same problem, the file download and is stored in the device, but after a while, all stored files are deleted

Comment: By default it would save in temp directory unless you specify a path. I reckon you save it in either application or document directory. Note, paths for android/ios devices are different.